# SharpDevelop error: "The tools version '12.0' is unrecognized..."

Tags: vb.net, sharpdevelop

I've been developing a vb.net project using Excel-DNA for the last few months using SharpDevelop and all of a sudden, when I open my project as usual, I have this error:

> The tools version "12.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "2.0", "3.5", "4.0". C:\path\to\file.vbproj

I'm gessing the falty codes is this part:
`<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`. As far as I can go in my Mercurial history it has always had this value.

Any idea of what could have created the problem? I had installed Visual Studio to test it out and see if the investement was worth it and uninstalled it lately, could it have something to do with that?

Comment: Uninstalling it wasn't a great idea, that took out the msbuild targets as well.  The VS uninstaller wasn't written to support SharpDevelop.

Comment: @HansPassant: if you could write down a quick anser with what you said I'de be happy to chose your answer. I've installed VS Express to have the MSBuild target back and it work like a charme again!

Comment: Just write your own answer and mark it.  Installing VS when you said you didn't like it would not have been my advice.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to edit the ToolsVersion in the project file, to set it to one of the available versions.

Comment: @Govert: That was a solution too, but wasn't sure if I'd loose some features

Comment: Same error in Blend,VS 2012

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like the MSBuild .target files necessary to support ToolsVersion 12.0 were uninstalled together with Visual Studio.

However, they are also available as a standalone download: [Microsoft Build Tools 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40760)

Comment: As a note, Build Tools 2013 is version 12.0. Build Tools 2015 is version 14.0.