# .NET Core 3.1 after updating Interaction Trigger and Prism no SelectionChanged event was firing

Tags: wpf, prism, .net-core-3.1, interaction

Today I have changed all my interaction triggers from http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity to http //schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors. Now my problem is, that no `selectionChanged` event was firing in the view model. My datasource is the view model.

My code:

```
<ComboBox Name="CBGL" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Troughs}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="TroughNumber"  SelectedValuePath="Id" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Model.Trough}" Width="173">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
               <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding CBGLRegionChangedCmd}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

If someone changes the selection, `CBGLRegionChangedCmd` is not firing.

The code from the view model:

```
CBGLRegionChangedCmd = new MyICommand(InvokeCommandAction_Changed);
```

If I undo the update all is working fine...

Comment: Any of these answers help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743961/the-name-interaction-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-http-schemas-microsoft

Answer (score 0):

You must added ViewModel to this question for best answer.
but i think your binding in SelectedValue="{Binding Model.Trough}" is wrong
please define a property full inside viewmodel with type Trough and xxx name then call inside it a notifyPropertyChange() method then set SelectedItem="{Binding xxx,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

alse you can set a property full inside viewmodel of type int with name yyy and bind it to SelectedValue property for example:
SelectedValue="{Binding yyy,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"