# subexpressions in indexers?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

```
Path=[Items[0].Name]
```

Is it possible?

The reason why I ask because this post [How to save the IsExpanded state in group headers of a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808777/how-to-save-the-isexpanded-state-in-group-headers-of-a-listview?lq=1) seems to imply that it is possible. However, I have been unable to get it to work or see any documentation that claims this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

That example should work without the square brackets.

```
{Binding Path=Items[0].Name}
```

In other situations, you might need to using the Source property of the Binding. For example:

```
{Binding Path=Name, Source={Binding Path=Items[0]}}
```

Comment: please reference the linked article for context; [Items[0].Name] and Items[0].Name are not the same thing. I asked if subexpressions in indexers is allowed.